# Collapsing multiple rows by a single cell/identifier

Tags: r

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I can't find a solution that works for my dataset.

I'm trying to collapse multiple rows of a R dataframe by a single unique identifier ("ICP" column). So this would ideally only combine all the cells of the ICP column which match, whilst leaving the other columns untouched. Thus each "row" can contain multiple rows within, so like a data table maybe?

I'd like to reshape the data from this:
[Sample of original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSCyB.png)

To this: [New dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJCLq.png)

Greatly appreciate the help :)

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `duplicated`.  Get a logical index of all duplicate elements in 'ICP with `duplicated` and assign it to blank (`""`)

```
df1$ICP[duplicated(df1$ICP)] <- ""
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response, the code you've provided gives the following warning message and makes duplicated ICPs NA rather than merged?
_Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, duplicated(df.3$ICP), value = c(1L, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated_

Comment: @Lucas I assumed that you have `character` class column.  Try `df1$ICP <- as.character(df1$ICP)` and then apply the code from the fresh data

Comment: @Lucas  Also, if you want to keep it as `factor` class, then create a new level for blank and then do the assignment ie. `levels(df1$ICP) <- c(levels(df1$ICP, "")`  It is better to assign it to `NA` instead of `""`

Comment: Ah okay I see what your code does, but is it possible to merge all the rows together akin to a data table format? So each unique ICP will have multiple rows within that row

Comment: @Lucas May be you need something like `library(tidyverse);df1 %>% group_by(ICP) %>% nest`